# jQuery slideToggle li when clicking another li

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I want to close (slideToggle) a listelement with an nested ul and li in it when clicking on another listelement with an nested ul and li in it.

This is my jQuery for the toggle itself:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul > li.closed").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target === this) {
            var li = $(this).closest('li');
            li.find(' > ul').slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).toggleClass("closed open");
        }
    });
});
```

On my fiddle: I want to close the "Topic 1" when clicking on "Topic 2".
And I want to close "Subtopic 1" when clicking on another "Subtopic x".

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rvUgH/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to first close all open lists then open clicked one :

remove rules in li.closed > ul

```
li.closed > ul {

}
```

*because* `display:none` *conflicts with* `slideToggle()` *when you click* **twice** *on the same* `li`

and change the script to

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#nav li ul").css('display','none');
    $("ul > li.closed").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target === this) {
            $(this).siblings("li.open").find(" > ul").slideToggle('fast',function(){
                $(this).parents("li.open:first").toggleClass("open closed");   
            });

            $(this).toggleClass("closed open").find(" > ul").slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. But now the slideToggle animation is gone. I don't want the elements to close in that static way. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Excellent! I didn't know the .siblings syntax before and very interesting with the display: none conflict! Thank you very much!